# How can I check if there is a specific parameter in a sails.js request?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How can I check whether there is a specific parameter inside `req.param()` in sails.js?

For example, I want to check whether the parameter `X_id` exists in `req.param()`. If the parameter exists, then I want to use it. If it doesn't exist, then I want to use a default value instead. I've tried the following code:

```
X_owner: req.param('X_id') || -1,
```

But I receive an error when I run this code with out `X_id` parameter. How can I fix the code?

Comment: This code looks right to me. Are you sure the `-1` value isn't causing the error further on?

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming to use default values for your parameters, I'd suggest using [actions2](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers#?actions-2) if you haven't tried. It lets you define parameters (using the inputs' object) and use `defaultsTo` on inputs you want to have default values for, just like in your models [attribute](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?default-values) definitions.  Using these should help resolve the issue.

As for how to check whether there is a specific parameter inside `req.param()`, you can use [req.allParams()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-all-params) to reveal all current parameters from all sources.  These include parameters parsed from the url path, the request body, and the query string in that order.